# Start a process from WCF service - performance issue - CPU load multiplies

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, process, cmd

I have a exe that process a document and generate another one from this. And i have a requeriment that need this process to be serve as a service, so i build a wcf service that internaly create a Process class to run this exe.

This works fine, the documents are generaty correctly, but i noticed a performance issue.

When a request come and the process is created, the cpu go this way:

running 1 instance of the process (cpu 50%)
 ->> http:// i.stack.imgur.com/Y04qZ.png
, running 2 instance of the process (cpu 100%)
- >> http:// i.stack.imgur.com/ltuNw.png
, running 4 instance of the process (cpu 100% more time)
- >> http:// i.stack.imgur.com/V8v4v.png

and when i start the same process from CMD, the CPU go this way running 4 instances (cpu low%)

->> http:// i.stack.imgur.com/cLIZm.png

the way im starting this process is this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = @rutaExe;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.Arguments = String.Format(" -subject {0} -file {1}",
            request.asunto,
            Path.Combine(rutaTemp, request.archivo_firmado));

using (Process exeProcess = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
            {
                exeProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    output = output + e.Data;
                };
                exeProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    err = err + e.Data;
                };
                exeProcess.Start();
                exeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
                exeProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
                exeProcess.WaitForExit(1000 * 6 * 15);
            }
```

Extra info, i noticed that the EXE internally calls the java runtime.

Is there a way this scenary can improve performance?

Comment: i noticed that JRE was not installer on the server, so i installed it but cpu initial load stills.

Comment: Also, I checked that each call for the EXE start the Java Runtime and no reuse a previous instance resource. Maybe there is a way to keep up the Java Runtime and be shared between calls.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I can't see anything wrong, except for the string concatenations in the `OutputDataReceived` and `ErrorDataReceived` delegates. If the process you're starting spits out a lot of output, your program is going to do a lot of avoidable memory allocations and put a lot of pressure on the garbage collector.

Without using a profiler (which you should be using), my guess would be to replace the `output` and `err` `string` variables with `StringBuilder`:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = @rutaExe;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.Arguments = String.Format(" -subject {0} -file {1}",
        request.asunto,
        Path.Combine(rutaTemp, request.archivo_firmado));

var output = new StringBuilder();
var err = new StringBuilder();

using (Process exeProcess = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
{
    exeProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            output.Append(e.Data);
        }
    };
    exeProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            err.Append(e.Data);
        }
    };
    exeProcess.Start();
    exeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    exeProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
    exeProcess.WaitForExit(1000 * 6 * 15);
}
```

You can get the resulting strings afterwards by calling the `StringBuilder`'s `ToString()` method.

A good rule of thumb is to *always* use a `StringBuilder` if you're going to be doing many concatenations, or if you don't know how many concatenations might be done by your code.

Lastly it's always a good idea to profile your code. Trying to guess what is causing the performance bottleneck is almost always a waste of time since the problem may be completely unintuitive!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response,  i used only a string because the process just response a code result and can be written in the standardoutput or standarderror.

Comment: I see. In that case you'll need to profile your code and see what is consuming so much CPU time.

I've used PerfView quite successfully for this type of thing in the past: its interface is a bit archaic but its free and does a great job once you get the hang of it.